# Can you explain the ngList Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the code for the ngList directive that AngularJS developed. I would like to implement something similar to it but i don't understand parts of the code. Here is the code

```
var ngListDirective = function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      var match = /\/(.*)\//.exec(attr.ngList),
          separator = match && new RegExp(match[1]) || attr.ngList || ',';

      var parse = function(viewValue) {
        var list = [];

        if (viewValue) {
          forEach(viewValue.split(separator), function(value) {
            if (value) list.push(trim(value));
          });
        }

        return list;
      };

      ctrl.$parsers.push(parse);
      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (isArray(value)) {
          return value.join(', ');
        }

        return undefined;
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Here are the parts I do not understand:

- **function(scope, element, attr, ctrl)**: The ctrl variable. Where can I read more about this.
- **ctrl.$parsers.push(parse);**: Where can I read more about this usage
- **ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {**: I need to understand this as i will be trying to implement something similar
- **require: 'ngModel'**: Why is ngModel required

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngList

Comment: @TusharGupta That link doesn't answer any of the questions asked.

Comment: @JimSchubert That's why it is comment not posted as an answer.It for reference .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, kudos for reading source!

`ctrl` is the controller(s) of the required directive(s) (in this case coming from the `ngModel` found in `require:`)

$parsers and $formatters- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

In short, and keeping in mind that Angular has to track both the DOM representation of `ngModel` data as well as the Angular model's representation,  $parsers handles translating the DOM side representation of `ngModel` data into the angular model view of the data.  $formatters takes the model view and translates it into the DOM appropriate representation.  So they are a pair, $parsers goes from DOM to model, $formatters goes back.

Lastly, `ngModel`.  `ngList` processes `ngModel` data.  So it needs to find an `ngModel` directive that has that data ngList should process (which takes us full circle, back to `ctrl`)